# Promise в цикле при запросах из бд

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, promise

Есть метод в классе, который должен достать из базы данных из одной таблицы текущее значение проектов, из другой таблицы их историю в разбивке по проектам и сформировать в один объект. Метод сейчас выглядит так:

```js
showDepositorProjectsWithStory() {

  this.showDepositorsProjects()
    .then(projects => {

      for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
        projects[i].story = this.showDepositorProjectStory(projects[i].id, this.id)
          .then(story => {
            return story;
          })
      }

      Promise.all(projects)
        .then(result => {
          console.log('TCL: Depositors -> showDepositorProjectsWithStory -> result', result)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('TCL: Depositors -> showDepositorProjectsWithStory -> err', err)
    });
}
```

и этот код не работает, так как в итоге в консоль выводится `story: Promise { <pending> }`. При этом, остальные данные записаны правильно. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: .then(story => {
            return story;
          }) куда возвращаете

Comment: у вас метод 1 тирации возвращает проимс вот и все пралвьно работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) принимает массив `Promise`, а в данном случае ему передается массив результатов.

Вместо этого надо было собрать `story` в отдельный массив и именно его передать в `Promise.all`.

Кроме этого, результат `Promise.all` сейчас не ожидается.

Исправленный код может выглядеть так:

```js
showDepositorProjectsWithStory() {

  this.showDepositorsProjects()
    .then(projects =>
      Promise.all(projects.map(p => this.showDepositorProjectStory(p.id, this.id)))
      .then(result => projects.forEach((p, i) => p.story = result[i])))

    .then(result => {
      console.log('TCL: Depositors -> showDepositorProjectsWithStory -> result', result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('TCL: Depositors -> showDepositorProjectsWithStory -> err', err)
    });
}
```

---

Вариант с async/await

```
async showDepositorProjectsWithStory() {
  try {
    var projects = await this.showDepositorsProjects();
    var stories = await Promise.all(projects.map(p => this.showDepositorProjectStory(p.id, this.id)));

    projects.forEach((p, i) => p.story = stories[i]);

    console.log('TCL: Depositors -> showDepositorProjectsWithStory -> result', result);
  } catch(err) {
      console.log('TCL: Depositors -> showDepositorProjectsWithStory -> err', err)
  };
}
```

Comment: Первые 2 сторчи твоего ответа мне очень помогли) Спасибо за теорию, сделал по-своему, но принцип твой.

Answer (score 0):

После ответа @Grundy сделал следующее:

```js
showDepositorProjectsWithStory() {

  this.showDepositorsProjects()
    .then(projects => {

      var storeArray = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
        storeArray.push(this.showDepositorProjectStory(projects[i].id, this.id));
      }

      Promise.all(storeArray)
        .then(result => {
          projects.forEach((p, i) => p.story = result[i]);
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('TCL: Depositors -> showDepositorProjectsWithStory -> err', err)
    });

}
```

По ощущениям у него лаконичнее и короче код.

Comment: единственное отличие от варианта из моего ответа в том, что ты вместо `map` используешь цикл и массив, и по сути сам этот map реализуешь :)

Comment: Ну да, опыта маловато пока что, поэтому делаю более наглядный для себя вариант))

Answer (score -1):

```
function showDepositorProjectsWithStory() {

    this.showDepositorsProjects().then(projects => {



  }

  /// Вызов 

  showDepositorProjectsWithStory().then(data => {
      data;
  })
```

Comment: Попробовал Вашим методом, `storeArray` в итоге пустой.

Comment: не понятно у вас projets это массив промисво или это массив обектво вы в цикле к его свойствам обращаетись  и потом его как массвив промисов выполняте

Comment: как то так  будет я изменил ответ.

Comment: В идеале в `projects` должен быть массив проектов, каждый проект - это объект, который мне нужно заполнить данными, одно из полей этого объекта должна быть история конкретного проекта. То есть я пытаюсь, перебирая поочередно каждый проект, вытащить только его историю и записать в этот объект

Answer (score -1):

Альтернативный вариант с использованием `async\await`.

```js
showDepositorProjectsWithStory() {

  this.showDepositorsProjects()
    .then(async projects => {

      for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
        projects[i].story = await this.showDepositorProjectStory(projects[i].id, this.id);
      }
      console.log('TCL: Depositors -> showDepositorProjectsWithStory -> result', projects)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('TCL: Depositors -> showDepositorProjectsWithStory -> err', err)
    });
}
```

Comment: У этого альтернативного варианта наблюдаемое поведение также альтернативно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov если вы о параллельных\последовательных запросах, то на результат это не влияет.

Comment: время выполнения - тоже результат

Comment: @PavelMayorov оставим это на решение ТС